# How do you set variable in route and display in template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am looking to set a variable for each page that is set to text to display as a dynamic header sort of thing. How would I set a variable in a route and display it in the corresponding template? So far everything I have tried is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of a template in a route is its controller, not its route. Try moving the action to the controller.

See updated twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/b454e10355ae8c708c3b8dc24b51e44e?openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C

For more information about controllers: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/controllers/

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass route variable to the template by using `model` hook. However, `model` is called only once. In order to update route variable and see its final value in the template, you need to **wrap** the variable. After that, you need to update the variable inside wrapped and the referance of the wrapped will not be changed. Your code will be like:

**route.js:**

```
model(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('myWrappedVariable', {myVariable: 1});
    let modelResult = {myWrappedVariable: this.get('myWrappedVariable')};

    return modelResult;
},

actions:{
    increaseVariables(){
        Ember.set(this.get('myWrappedVariable'), 'myVariable', this.get('myWrappedVariable.myVariable')+1);
    }
}
```

**template.hbs**

```
myWrappedVariable: {{model.myWrappedVariable.myVariable}}
```

[Take a look at this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b454e10355ae8c708c3b8dc24b51e44e?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C) for this usage.

Comment: Thanks. Can I return multiple items? If in my route I am already doing this: return this.store.findAll('servicerequest'); Is there a way to add variables for return too?

Comment: @spacerobot I've addressed that question as part of an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav answer is totally right and should be considered as best practice. However if you have a good reason for setting a variable, which is not the model, in a Route, you could use [`setupController`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController) hook therefore:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    // Call _super for default behavior
    this._super(controller, model);

    // Set a variable on controller
    controller.set('foo', 'bar');
  }
});
```

As shown in the api docs you could also use `setupController` to set a variable on another controller by getting an instance of it using [`controllerFor`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/Route/methods/controllerFor?anchor=controllerFor) method. However I would not consider this a good practice, cause if it's not well documented throughout the application, it's quite hard to maintain such code.

As shown by @Ahmet Emre Kılınç's answer you could also use a hash as model. If at least one of it's properties is a Promise, you should return a [`RSVP.hash()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/functions/rsvp/hash). Otherwise [`model` hook](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/classes/Route/methods/model?anchor=model) would not block the transition until the Promise is fulfilled.